# Graphviz set edge initial direction

Tags: graphviz, dot

When I draw a diagram with `spline=ortho` graphviz sometimes draws edges that go down and then left or right:

```
 +--[ ]
 |   |
 v   |
[ ]  +->[ ]
```

How can I specify that edges should depart horizontally from a node?

```
 +--[ ]--+
 |       |
 v       v
[ ]     [ ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently (Version 2.38) not working. The compass points are not implemented for spline=ortho. see [Issue 352](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/352)